# How do I change the delete function so it deletes a specific user rather than the whole users list

Tags: php, debugging, backend, sql-delete

I have a list of users that are registered to a website and I want to delete a specific user when the delete link is pressed, but I am having an issue where all the users are being deleted once I open the page of the users list.

Here is the users list, where `$users` is an array that contains the list of users:

```
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
      <tr>
         <th><?= $user->name ?></th>
         <td><?= $user->email ?></td>
         <td><a href="<?php $user->delete()>?">Delete</a></td>
         <td><a href="">Update</a></td>
          </form>
       </tr>
    <?php endforeach?>
```

Here is the delete function of `$user`:

```
  public function delete(){
        $result=$this->db->delete("users","id={$this->id}");
        return $result;
    }
```

And here is the Database delete function:

```
public function delete(string $table,string $where,int $limit=1){
        return $this->connection->exec("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $where LIMIT $limit");
    }
```

How do I make it that specific user is deleted when the link Delete is pressed?!

I tried to change the delete functions but did not achieve a result.

Comment: You are open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even data from the database, [you are still at risk of corrupting your data](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Thank you Jason, This is just a school project but I will make sure to add it on later tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this piece of code:

```
 <td><a href="<?php $user->delete()>?">Delete</a></td>
```

the problem is that when you call the page you are deleting the users directly instead of printing a link to a deletion page.

you need to create a separete route (or a .php file if you aren't using a framework) such as delete_user.php?user_id={your_user_id} or /{user_id}/delete ( in a framework scenario)

this route/page has to check if the user passed in to the page exists ad then delete it, by getting the user from the db and than call the `delete()` method.

after that your code will be similar to the following in a php framework scenario:

```
 <td><a href="http://www.example.com/<?php $user->id?>"/delete>Delete</a></td>
```

or like this in a standalone scenario:

```
 <td><a href="http://www.example.com/delete_user.php?user_id=<?php $user->id?>">Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: Hey JDarwind, Thank you so much for your response, I did it this way and it seems to work, but I had to change the delete function of the user to accept an id parameter and I have to create a user with null fields and use the delete function, I am not sure if this is the best approach to fix this issue, this is the code I wrote: `if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
$user = new User();
$user->delete($id);` Do you have any different approach to the solution?

Comment: You could also create a static declared `static function getById($id)` method in your users class, so you can call `Users::getById($id)->delete();` method, or even a straight up `Users::deletById($id)` to perform this directly without the need to instantiate a user object.

Comment: Thank you so much, works perfectly well, I also have to do the deletion for articles, should I do it the same way but as a new separate file or is it possible to do it by adding code to this file?!

Comment: I think you can use the same approach. You can also extends the base model class and create for example a cust model class with a public static method for deletion and then you can use the custom model class  a base class fo your models. In this scenario you Will have the custom deletion method defined for all' your models